# Error while importing shapefile using shp2pgsql: Coordinate values are out of range

Tags: shapefile, postgresql

I have a shapefile with 180 points. I'm using shp2pgsql-gui via pgAdminIII. This is an error it gives me when I try to import shapefile.

```
Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR:  Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type
```

This is information about coordinate system:

```
Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you checked if your coordinates are indeed in degrees?

Comment: How to check that?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do it with the GUI but using the command line you should try to force the srid

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 shapefile.shp schema.table > table.sql
```

Then you can execute the table.sql script from pgadmin

Comment: It still gives me that error.

Comment: I reprojected in WGS84 in GRASS, and now there's no error!